# heap-buffer-overflow on 3Sum implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to resolve the problem of 3Sum in LeetCode. However, I can't deal with this error which is called "heap-buffer-overflow".

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    int numslen = nums.size();
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    int i = 0;
    while(i < numslen - 2){
        int start = i + 1;
        int end = numslen - 1;
        while (start < end) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[start] + nums[end] == 0) {
                res.push_back({ nums[i], nums[start], nums[end] });
                end--;
                while (nums[end] == nums[end+1]) { end--;   }
            }
            else if (nums[i] + nums[start] + nums[end] > 0) { end--; }
            else { start++; }
        }
        i++;
        while (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) { i++;   }
    }   
    return res;
}
```

This is the error message.

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000044c at pc 0x000000406c74 bp 0x7ffd2a1cd0d0 sp 0x7ffd2a1cd0c8
```

Comment: Watch out for overstepping the bounds with `i` and `end`. Suppose, for instance, that your input is a vector with three identical numbers...

Comment: And please show us how you called this function when you got that error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) { i++;}
```

should be

```
while (i < numslen && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) { i++;}
```

The first time the loop above is executed, i and i-1 are guaranteed to be within range. But what if the `nums` have trailing duplicate numbers ? Your version will read *"forever"* on invalid memory.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. But there is another bug I just found that can also make this wrong message. `while (nums[end] == nums[end+1]) { end--;}` should be `while (start < end && nums[end] == nums[end+1]) { end--;}`.

Comment: @KongJohn I am getting no error when I run your code for a small vector. Could you please show us how you call the function (specially the input vector)?

Comment: @KongJohn yes both are similar.

Comment: @AKL You can try following code:```vector<vector<int>> res;
 vector<int> nums = {0,0,0};
 res = threeSum(nums);```, and you will realize the bug.